# cxf - parsing soap messages element's attribute

Tags: parsing, soap, attributes, request, cxf

I'm getting a soap request like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notifications xmlns="xxxxx">
            <sometags></sometags>
            <Notification>
                <Id>yyyyy</Id>
                <sObject xsi:type="sf:Dog" xmlns:sf="urn:some.enterprise.object.soap.com">
                    <sf:Id>zzzzz</sf:Id>
                </sObject>
            </Notification>
        </notifications>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and I want to find out what kind of object is the notification about (== I want to read the sObject's type attribute, so 
that I know whos type of sObject is related the **id** tag).

---

I want to be able to do something similar:

if (sObject.type.equals("Dog")) 
//do something

if (sObject.type.equals("Cat"))
//do something else

but how can i get that attribute value in the soap request?

I'm using java with cxf libraries .

Thank you,

Cloutz

Comment: Do you have WSDL for this service?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Interceptor & do what ever you want.